# Apache "url translation"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I have an apache 2.4 running in ubuntu 16. It serves some gz compressed html files and it compresses them on the fly. This is my .htaccess:

```
AddEncoding gzip .gz

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Konqueror
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css$ $1.css.gz [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js$ $1.js.gz [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.html.gz [QSA,L]

<Files *.gz>
ForceType text/html
</Files>
```

what i am now trying to achieves, is the following:

lets say that a user hits through a browser the following:

http://myapache/myrootdir/file1

i want him to be redirected but without seeing it (the url in the browser must remain as is) to one of the compressed gz files mentioned above (file1 does not exist in the server).

e.g http://myapache/myrootdir/file1.html.gz

is this somehow possible? I tried several ways with mod_rewrite without success. Any thoughts or ideas are highly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i finally did was the following modification in my .htacess file.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule file1.html file1.html.gz [QSA,L]
```

I still have to add the .html extension but it is acceptable.